# Adding specific bindings per RequestContext

Tags: quarkus, requestcontext

Within a `@RequestScoped`, is it possible to add bindings that are only valid for that request?  i.e, any injection of beans within that context get a request specific instance (say singleton)?

Comment: I find this question fairly hard to decipher, but if I understand correctly, the answer is: you don't have to worry about injecting beans with narrower scope into beans with wider scope (or the opposite), it works correctly due to the usage of client proxies. If you want per-request beans, make them `@RequestScoped`. It doesn't matter where you inject those beans -- it may be into other `@RequestScoped` beans, there's no problem with that.

Comment: @Ladicek thank you.  Let us assume there are multiple "customers" and each request contains a "customer" in its HTTP request header or a security token.  I want any bean that is `@RequestScoped` to be able to do:

```
@Inject
private Customer customer;
```

and the correct customer is injected in it.  Is there a way to instruct the `RequestScope` what that instance is from the security token?

Comment: Your `Customer` should be `@RequestScoped`. Most likely, you will want to use a producer method to define the `Customer` bean, where the producer will declare as a parameter the request or the token or the current security identity (those are all beans in Quarkus, and producer method parameters are injection points) and based on that parameter, instantiate the `Customer` object.